# Send value from child component to parent in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component : SiteAdd, and inside, I have a radioIcon custom component, that should send a a `site_kind` param to SiteAdd form.

The parent `SiteAdd`:

```
return (
        <Fragment>
            <ColumnWithPaddingTop>
                <SingleColumnPage>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
                        
                        <Checkbox
                            {...three_phase}
                            label={I18n.t('three-phase site')}
                            position='right'
                        />
                        <SiteKind {...useField('site_kind')}/>
                        <Submit state={state}/>
                    </form>
                </SingleColumnPage>
            </ColumnWithPaddingTop >
        </Fragment>
```

The child `SiteKind`:

```
function onTrigger(event) {
    console.log('changed');
    this.props.parentCallback('Data from child');
    event.preventDefault();
}
function SiteKind() {
    const { useField } = useForm({ three_phase: false });
    const site_kind = useField('site_kind');

    return (
        <SquaredCheckboxOrRadioRow label={I18n.t('site kind')} {...site_kind} onChange = {onTrigger}>
        <Radio
            choice='residential' {...site_kind}
            content={<RadioContent label={I18n.t('residential')} />}
        />
         <Radio
            choice='tertiary' {...site_kind}
            content={<RadioContent label={I18n.t('tertiary')}  />}
        />
    </SquaredCheckboxOrRadioRow>
    );
}
```

I cannot receive the value of `site_kind` in parent form.

Also, in the child, the `onTrigger()` method is never called. Why ? How should I pass the value to parent form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Put the state inside the parent component and pass the value and setter to the child component as props.

```
function Parent() {
    const { useField } = useForm({ three_phase: false });
    const site_kind = useField('site_kind');

    // you now have access to `site_kind` in the parent

    return <Child site_kind={site_kind} />
}

function Child({ site_kind }) {
    // whatever you had before, but `site_kind` is coming from props
}
```